# Umbraco 10 : Detection of browser / userAgent on localhost

Tags: c#, razor, localhost, umbraco

I have installed an instance V12 locally.
I'm trying to check for mobile and other devices

The error message im getting is this one:

***An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.***

- **The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context**

  - **@if(Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice && !Request.UserAgent.Contains("iPad") && !Request.UserAgent.Contains("Tablet"))**

My code :

```
@inherits Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage;
@{
    var imageCrop = Model.MacroParameters["crop"].ToString();
}


<div class="heading">
        <div class="heading01">@Model.Content.Value("bannerTitle")</div>
        <div class="heading02">@Model.Content.Value("bannerSubtitle")</div>
</div>

@if(Model.Content.HasValue("videoLink"))
{
    <div class="play-video" data-fancybox href="@Model.Content.Value("videoLink")">
        <span>
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 17 21">              
            <polygon points="16.9,10.5 0.1,21 0.1,0 "/>
            </svg>
        </span>
    </div>
}

<div class="overlay"></div>

@if(Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice && !Request.UserAgent.Contains("iPad") && !Request.UserAgent.Contains("Tablet"))
    {
        <img src="@Model.Content.GetCropUrl("bannerImage", "mobile")" class="img-fluid" alt="@Model.Content.Value("altTag")" />
    }
    else 
    {
        if(imageCrop == "crop")
        {
            <img src="@Model.Content.GetCropUrl("bannerImage", "crop")" class="img-fluid" alt="@Model.Content.Value("altTag")" />
        }
        else
        {
            <img src="@Model.Content.GetCropUrl("bannerImage", "full")" class="img-fluid" alt="@Model.Content.Value("altTag")" />
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're trying to access the Request object from within a razor view?

Then I think the issue isn't really related with umbraco (which I don't really know) but with ASP.NET razor views in general.

As the error says (*"The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context"*) it doesn't know, what "Request" is. So you cannot access it directly. But any razor page gives you access to the HttpContext via its `Context` property (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorpage.context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-razor-razorpage-context)).

So you can change

```
@if(Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice ...
```

to

```
@if(Context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice ...
```